# Headers already sent - from which PHP version has this been changed?

Tags: php

I have always had a warning message when outputting text before a header() tag.

However, a while ago I noticed I couldn't get PHP to display the error anymore. And this was when upgrading the VPS it was on.

This is the code I used:

```
<?
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  echo "this should show me an error";
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  phpinfo();
?>
```

On PHP Version 5.2.6 -- I see the error.
On PHP Version 5.3.3 -- I don't see the error.

**My question is:** From which version was this fixed -- or am I missing something here?

Comment: This has always been how it worked. Check your php.ini settings to make sure error reporting hasn't changed.

Comment: It's probably a config setting. You can configure PHP to force error_reporting off so even a local php.ini file cant overwrite it.

Comment: Made the error_reporting exactly the same (display_errors = On & error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE) -- nothing changes, I cannot see the errors at all. This is on two different VPS systems I'm testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check php.ini output_buffering configuration. Set value of output_buffering to 0 and restart your server

Comment: You're right, this was the problem. On the newer system it was set to 4096, and when I set it to 0 - it was showing the error.